# asp.net c# current date is not inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net-entity-data-model

```
user_info.join_date = DateTime.Now;
db.SaveChanges();
```

my table have join_date column that have date type
problem is that date is not inserted to database but other values is inserted to database...at the same time.
date is showing as 11/11/2015 12:00:00 but not inserted
please help me

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see wich commands are been sent to te DDBB.

Comment: how can i see that @Oscar

Comment: Using SQL Profiler, a tool that's shipped with SQL Database

Comment: Do you get an error? Please show the `user_info` entity, and please show more user_info property update code.

Comment: Is your data type 'Date' or 'DateTime' ?

Comment: Log queries you're executing somewhere (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804783/log-queries-executed-by-entity-framework-dbcontext) and check what SQL statement is executed.

Comment: no i dont have any error...but date is not inserted @markpsmith

Comment: Can you show some more code then?