# Why is EF so slow to get data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm still learning how to use EF but I'm not sure why it's taking me so long to pull data from the database.

My EF statement:

```
    IEnumerable<DOC_TRACK_MAIN> data;
    Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
    st.Start();

    data = context.TABLE1.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.TABLE2).AsNoTracking().Where(x => startDate <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) && endDate >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LAST_UPDATED_DATE));            

    var result = data.Where(x => x.TABLE2.MAP_TYPE_CODE.Trim().ToUpper() == reportCode.Trim().ToString()).ToList();
    st.Stop();
    var cnt = result.Count();
    var tm = st.Elapsed;
    return result;
```

When I test a similar query in TOAD it takes about 5 seconds..

Comment: How long does the EF query take to execute? Also, did you try to log actual query produced by EF?

Comment: It's taking minutes to execute, if it doesn't give me an out of memory exception.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the query log.

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804783/log-queries-executed-by-entity-framework-dbcontext - you can use `DbContext.Database.Log` to sniff queries as they go to the database. See if this query is truly joining with `TABLE2` or it ignores the Include call - that is what may have happened.

Comment: OK I'm still playing with that to get the output.  I'm not sure about ignoring the include call.  When I do get data it is the TABLE1 with a nav property of TABLE2 with its data in it.  Problem is that it's taking 1:14 to return 478 items back into a list.

Comment: is that `TABLE2` collection or single object ?

Comment: It's an object.  Should I be seeing the same object over and over again as I go through the nav properties?  ie. table1.table2  then if I look at table2 there is a table1 property listing all those fields etc...

Comment: *It's a single object

Comment: -- Executing at 8/27/2016 8:31:20 PM -04:00
-- Completed in 4139 ms with result: OracleDataReader
Does this mean my issue could be with the generating of the list from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Performance Improvement :**

*OP's Original Query :* **1:14 Min**

*Solution below :* **0.06 Min**

*Improved % :* **1800 %**

Please rewrite your EF Query as shown below and let us know about the performance now.

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;//to remove lazy loading for this query only

data = context.TABLE1.Where(x => startDate <= 
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) && endDate >= 
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LAST_UPDATED_DATE)).Include(x => x.TABLE2);   

var result = data.Where(x => x.TABLE2.MAP_TYPE_CODE.Trim().ToUpper() == 
reportCode.Trim().ToString()).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: I want to return all of the contents of table1 and table 2.

Comment: Updated.Please see now.

Comment: is that fast now ?

Comment: Getting syntax error on last line.  I will need to take a look at that.

Comment: Now I need to understand what you did so I can do that moving forward.

Comment: This couldn't be true. OP is using eager loading, so lazy loading has nothing in common with the issue. Most likely the problem is in this declaration `IEnumerable<DOC_TRACK_MAIN> data`. All you need is to change `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable`.

Comment: @IvanStoev We cannot say it by looking at OP's query.B'cos he didn't put the models.Let's say if `TABLE1` has lot of `navigational properties`.Then what will happen ? All the properties will load with the data if we didn't disable the `LazyLoading` for that query.That is the case here I think.That's why this much of performance gain.

Comment: And may I ask **why** will they load? **Lazy** means they will load when some code tries to access the property, but there is no such code. No, this is not a good direction for EF learners. The key is `IQueryable` (db query) vs `IEnumerable` (in memory query). It's obvious that OP thinks his code is executing a single db query retrieving 478 records, while in reality it's taking much more records from the database and filtering them in memory (the second `Where`).

Comment: @IvanStoev OK,then can you tell me how above solution gave over `1800%` gain ? And thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: The only logical explanation is that `Include` somehow has been ignored in the original query, so the second query `Where` was causing lazy load of the `TABLE2` navigation property. So the fix could be actually how you rewrote the query (moving the `Include` to a different place in the chain, removing `AsNoTracking` etc.), not turning the lazy load off. The full EF log would easily show what was the case. In any case, what OP claims doesn't change the [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) style of the answer. Btw, your code does not even compile :)

Comment: hmm..who will expect to compile SO editor code snippets ?  :D But OP got the idea and sorted out his issue.But I'm really appreciate your feedback here.We have to think so many ways even though we have a good result. Which is very good :) Have a nice day to you @IvanStoev  :)

Comment: Same to you @Sampath :)

Comment: So that I understand I had several things wrong with my original query.
1. I used IEnumerable instead of IQuerable this means memory vs db query processing? 
2. I would still like to understand how  see if the include is missing?

Comment: FYI for the record I went back to my original query.  Around 6 secs if I change IEnumerable to IQueryable and set LazyLoading to false.  9 seconds if I only change IEnumerable to IQueryable.