# When should I use navigation properties to query the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my Entity Framework 6 application, I have a table of people's email addresses:

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Person` object references these email addresses also:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    {...}

    public virtual ICollection<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to get all the email addresses for a single person ***and*** check whether the person actually exists, would it be more efficient to either:

1. Run an `Any()` query on the `Persons` table and then another query on the `EmailAddresses` table, using `PersonId` as a parameter:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetAddressesByPerson(int personId)
   {
       if (!Context.Persons.Any(x => x.Id == personId))
       {
           throw new Exception("Person not found");
       }

       return Context.EmailAddresses.Where(x => x.PersonId == personId).ToList();
   }
   ```
2. Get the `Person` object and return the `EmailAddresses` navigation property:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetAddressesByPerson(int personId)
   {
       var person = Context.Persons.Find(personId);

       if (person == null)
       {
           throw new Exception("Person not found")
       }

       return person.EmailAddress;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of 1st solution, EF will generate sql query which includes `EXISTS` statement. Then, if it exits you will execute completely different 2nd query against to the database.

In case of 2nd solution, you will send just a `select ... from Persons where ..` statement. And as you set `EmailAddress` as navigational property, if `Lazy Loading` is enabled then EF will generate and execute query against `EmailAdress` table based on `personId`. If `Lazy Loading` is not enabled, then `EmailAddress` will be null or empty.

As a 3rd option you use `Eager Loading` feature, which will let EF to generate `join` query and will fecth `person` and related `EmailAddress`es in one go.

So, if mostly you expect to have correct `personId`, then you can switch to `Eager Loading` mode. `Lazy Loading` is mostly helpful in scnearios, when you need to fetch related entities only in some cases.

By the way, I suggest you to [turn on logging in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804783/log-queries-executed-by-entity-framework-dbcontext), to see generated queries.

As a result, here is the code sample for loading related entities eagerly:

```
var person = Context.Persons
            .Include(s ⇒ s.EmailAddresses)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == personId);
```

The key point is to add a call to `Include` method and pass the navigational property. Passed entity will be loaded eagerly. And at the end of query you can use any of the methods which will do immediate execution, like `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `ToList` and so on. 
You can't use `Include`  with `Find`, because the latter one is the method of `DbSet`. In your case the most relevant one is `Single`, which will automatically throw exception if there is no person in the table with the specified id.

Answer (score 1):

An option:

```
public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetAddressesByPerson(int personId)
{
    var queryResults = Context.Persons
        .Where(x => x.Id == personId)
        .Select(x => new { EmailAddresses = x.EmailAddresses })
        .Single(); 

    return queryResults.EmailAddresses;
}
```

The above query asserts that a single Person's e-mail addresses should be returned. You could do a `SingleOrDefault` and then check the result for #null to customize the error message, though I tend to keep exception messages pure. We then return the selected collection. So if a person exists, but has no e-mail addresses, you'll receive an empty list. If the person doesn't exist you'll get an Expected 1, found 0 exception. If more than one person exists for the Id (shouldn't, but...) you'll get an Expected 1, found more than one exception.  Don't use `FirstOrDefault` unless you expect more than one is possible and provide an `OrderBy` to ensure the data order is predictable.